# arch linux intellij core dump

Tags: intellij-idea, archlinux, coredump

My Intellij wont start anymore, i really dont know why.
Heres the Log File:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f18a8424be0, pid=12079, tid=139743934207744
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_60-b27) (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.60-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f18a8424be0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

i tried ulimit -c unlimited but that didint worked aswell.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check arch linux forums? I found that: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46619
Did downgrading glib2 helped?